# Does the ignoredFiles field impact manual triggers in Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

The [REST API for Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.triggers#BuildTrigger) describes a field called ignoredFiles[] which specifies the following:

> If ignoredFiles is not empty, then we ignore any files that match any of the ignored_file globs. If the change has no files that are outside of the ignoredFiles globs, then we do not trigger a build.

Does this field have any effect on manual triggers? For example, if I have a file that's included in the ignored files, it is the only one to change between builds, and then I manually invoke the build trigger, will it still create the build or will it skip since there is only a change in the ignored file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a manual build with exclusion file. You have to define a sourceToBuild instead, without any filter.

The filter are made to accept or discard automatically SCM events. In your case, you haven't SCM event, it's YOUR event.